# What is the safe method to remove a list of empty directories?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I use `Path.iterdir()` to go through a list of directories and do so some work.

```
from pathlib import Path

for folder in repository.iterdir():
    # do some work
```

After completing that task, if it's successful the directories should be empty. I'm aware that you shouldn't [modify a list you're iterating over](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223918/iterating-through-a-collection-avoiding-concurrentmodificationexception-when-re), so doing this I assume would be bad practice, correct?

```
for folder in repository.iterdir():
    folder.rmdir()
```

Instead what I did was collect a list of directories that are empty and then use that list to remove the directories, like this:

```
# Get a list of all the directories that are empty.
directories_to_remove = [folder for folder in repository.iterdir() if not os.listdir(folder)]

# Remove all the directories that are empty
for folder in directories_to_remove:
    folder.rmdir()
```

The folder paths still exists in `directories_to_remove` so I'm not modifying a list I'm iterating over, is this the correct way to delete the directories from the drive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a correct way to *remove the actual directory*, but you are correct in that you are not removing it from `directories_to_remove`

If you'd like to, you could simply change:

```
for folder in directories_to_remove:
    folder.rmdir()

to

for folder in directories_to_remove:
    folder.rmdir()
    directories_to_remove.remove(folder)
```

But, if your intentions are to not remove it from the list while iterating, you are succeeding, good job :)

Comment: The second piece of code is exactly what one _should't_ do. Check what this code outputs: `a = [1,2,3]; for x in a: a.remove(x); print(a)`. Note how it doesn't output an empty list after the loop.

Comment: Correct, and I don't think I implied you should do that (if I did, I need to check my English :)), but I was unsure if the OP had an intention to do that.

Comment: The point is, removing items from a list while iterating over it [_doesn't work_](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1207427/4354477)

Comment: @JerryM. - I don't want to remove the directories from the `directories_to_remove` list while iterating over it.  I can do it all at once afterward, correct? With `directories_to_remove.clear()`?

Comment: Absolutely correct! You should not remove things while iterating. Once you are done, you can use `.clear()` to completely remove everything from the list. See the reference here: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/list/clear

Answer (score 0):

[`iterdir` doesn't remove a list](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.iterdir), so you're good. Moreover, if it did return a list, your code doesn't delete any items from it, so it would've been fine anyway, as long as the directories are actually deleted, of course.

Answer (score 0):

What happens when iterating over data in Python is determined by the `iterator` and problems are likely to occure when altering the `iterable` this `iterator` refers to. If you do iterate over a list that was created once, you can maipulate the data it was created from without any harm. But since [iterdir](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.iterdir) "yields" values, it appears to be a `generator` thus it fetches the data on the fly, and whether or not bad things happen depends on its implementation (and/ or the implementation of the underlying system calls).

Unless you have severe performance or memory troubles I would not take the chance and fetch all data before processing it:

```
for folder in [repository.iterdir()]:
    folder.rmdir()
```

Note thought that this is not 100% safe either since there might be a case where the directories are filled, altered or removed before you hit the `folder.rmdir()` but this is highly unlikely unless you use multiprossessing.